# Triangle inequality in coordinate geometry

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

Let $P,Q,R$ denote points $(2,3),(4,-2),(h,0)$ respectively.

Find value of $h$ if  $|PR-RQ|$ is maximum.

My Attempt:
I am trying to use triangle inequality i.e.

$|PR-RQ|\leq PQ$

but not getting the answer.

Comment: It must give answer.

Comment: I think equality will hold when $P,Q,R$are collinear

Comment: Yes, that's right. Answer must be $\sqrt{29}$

Comment: No. The answer is 8

Comment: They have taken reflection of $Q$ w.r.t x-axis as $Q'$ , then they have found equation of line $PQ'$ and solved it with x-axis to obtain $R$. Why reflection has been taken by author is not clear. However on plotting the above situation on graph solution appears reasonable. But what is logic behind taking reflection of $Q$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can draw a picture, so we can see that we can not have $|PR-QR|=PQ$ because $Q$ can not be between $P$ and $R$ or $P$ can not be between $Q$ and $R$.

The motivation of taking the reflection of $Q$, namely $Q'$, is that we can have $Q'$ is between $P$ and $R$, and then we can use  triangle inequality and the equality can be happen

Another way: Consider the function $f(h)=\sqrt{h^2-4h+13}-\sqrt{h^2-8h+20}$, we can find that $f'(h)=0$ when $h=8$ or $h=16/5$, then max$|f(h)|$=$\sqrt{5}$ at $h=8$

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(x%5E2-4x%2B13)-sqrt(x%5E2-8x%2B20)

Comment: It is said, that $|PR-RQ|$ is maximum, not $|PR-QR|$

Comment: I think we are talking about the length

Comment: Yes, you are right - the length. I've edited my comment. But it still makes the differece.

Comment: @JaroslawMatlak: You need to see the difference between $|PR-RQ|$ and $|\vec{PR}-\vec{RQ}|$

Comment: Ok, now I see. Sorry.